# Getting persistent object from function parameter

Tags: c++, v8

Im currently implementing my user interface based on XML and Javascript. I have written a lot of wrapper classes and everything works fine so far. There is just one thing that bugs me. I am not able to create a persistent object from a parameter of one of my functions. Say i have the following function:

```
void UIManager::registerJSObject(JSObjectPtr objPtr) {
```

Which gets registered to Javascript using my wrappers the JSObject (wraps v8::Handle) is pointing to the local function parameter and therefore after the function it gets erased. Now obviously thats not what i want it to do.

My first approach was to add a makePersistent method to the JSObject class like that:

```
void JSObject::makePersistent() {
    v8::Persistent<v8::Object> newObj = v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::New(mObject);
    mObject = newObj;
}
```

Sadly it did not work and the object still gets garbage collected. So i thought maybe its too late when i do it there and it already has to be converted when its taken from the Arguments parameter of the callback for some reason and i changed my wrapper to this (just for testing):

```
template<uint32 size, typename T, typename... FullArgs, typename... Args>
Res expand(const v8::Arguments& args, Args... curArgs) {
    return expand<size + 1, FullArgs...>(args, curArgs..., ObjectWrap::unwrap<T>(v8::Persistent<v8::Value>::New(args[size])));
}
```

Sadly thats not working either. I am not able to get a persistent handle to an object allocated in javascript. Im talking about that code:

```
var frame = {
    xmlTemplate: "testXml.xml",

    onTemplateLoaded: function () {
        this.frame1.button1.Caption = "Test";
    },

    buttonClicked: function(button) {
        button.Caption = "Clicked";
    }
};

UIMgr.loadUIElement(frame);
```

and id like to invoke the buttonClicked function or set some fields not only in the UI.load function but also later.

Does anyone know if im missing something or if this is a bug?

Greetings Muepe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. I was already on the right track, the creation of the persistent handle has to be done on the original object, so i modified my expanding member function with a second overload especially for parameters that should get JSObject's.

Pretty much as seen before:

```
    template<uint32 size, typename T, typename... FullArgs, typename... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, JSObjectPtr>::value, Res>::type expand(const v8::Arguments& args, Args... curArgs) {
        return expand<size + 1, FullArgs...>(args, curArgs..., ObjectWrap::unwrap<T>(v8::Persistent<v8::Value>::New(args[size])));
    }
```

With the interesting part beeing in ObjectWrap::unwrap for JSObjectPtr:

```
    template<typename T>
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, JSObjectPtr>::value, JSObjectPtr>::type unwrap(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> val) {
        v8::Persistent<v8::Object> objh = v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::Cast(val);

        return std::make_shared<JSObject>(objh);
    }
```

It **HAS** to be passed as v8::Persistent to the function, else it wont work.

The JSObject has a constructor for persistent handles and converts it to a weak reference that gets invoked when no one uses the JSObject anymore (and thats when it actually has to be collected).